# How to fix "PI recursive function" code to work with all values of n?

Tags: c++, recursion

I'm working on a code that calculates PI with n terms. However, my code only works correctly with some values of n.

This piece of code even numbers do not work and when I switch up the negative sign the odd numbers do not work.

```
double PI(int n, double y=2){

    double sum = 0;
    if (n==0){
        return 3;
    }else if (n % 2 != 0){
        sum =  (4/(y*(y+1)*(y+2)))+(PI (n - 1 ,y+2)) ;

    }else{
        sum=  -(4/(y*(y+1)*(y+2)))+PI (n - 1,y+2)  ;
    }
    return sum;
} 

  int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    double n = PI (2,2);
    cout << n << endl;
   }
```

For n = 2 I expected a result of 3.1333 but I got a value of 2.86667
This is the formula for calculating PI , y is the denominator and n is the number of terms
[image]

Comment: I recommend adding the headers etc... the code needs so potential answerers can drop your example into text file, compile and run. I also recommend adding what you received instead of the expected. This extra bit of information often contains information that instantly suggests potential answers.

Comment: Could you show as the mathematical formula your code implements? What is `n` and `y`? Where did you get those expected values from?

Comment: BTW, every time you *recurse* you use up more stack memory (including normal function call data and local variables).  There is not enough stack space for *N* when *N* repetitions becomes large.  Prefer an iterative approach or use a stack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, I will assume that a complete runnable case of your code looks like

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

double PI(int n, double y=2){

    double sum = 0;
    if (n==0){
        return 3;
    }else if (n % 2 != 0){
        sum =  (4/(y*(y+1)*(y+2)))+(PI (n - 1 ,y+2)) ;

    }else{
        sum=  -(4/(y*(y+1)*(y+2)))+PI (n - 1,y+2)  ;
    }
    return sum;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
  double n = PI (2,2);
  cout << n << endl;
}
```

I believe that you are attempting to compute pi through the formula

```
(pi - 3)/4 = \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} (-1)^{k+1} / ((2k(2k+1)(2k+2)),
```

(where here and elsewhere I use LaTeX code to represent mathy things). This is a good formula that converges pretty quickly despite being so simple. If you were to use the first two terms of the sum, you would find that

```
(pi - 3)/4 \approx 1/(2*3*4) - 1/(4*5*6)  ==>  pi \approx 3.13333,
```

which you seem to indicate in your question.

To see what's wrong, you might trace through your first function call with PI(2, 2). This produces three terms.

1. n=2: 2 % 2 == 0, so the first term is `-4/(2*3*4) + PI(1, 4)`. This is the wrong sign.
2. n=1: 1 % 2 == 1, so the second term is `4/(4*5*6)`, which is also the wrong sign.
3. n=0: n == 0, so the third term is 3, which is the correct sign.

So you have computed

```
3 - 4/(2*3*4) + 4/(4*5*6)
```

and we can see that there are many sign errors.

The underlying reason is because you are determining the sign based on `n`, but if you examine the formula the sign depends on `y`. Or in particular, it depends on whether `y/2` is odd or even (in your formulation, where you are apparently only going to provide even `y` values to your sum).

You should change `y` and `n` appropriately. Or you might recognize that there is no reason to decouple them, and use something like the following code. In this code, `n` represents the number of terms to use and we compute `y` accordingly.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

double updatedPI(int n)
{
  int y = 2*n;
  if (n == 0) { return 3; }
  else if (n % 2 == 1)
  {
    return 4. / (y*(y + 1)*(y + 2)) + updatedPI(n-1);
  }
  else
  {
    return -4. / (y*(y + 1)*(y + 2)) + updatedPI(n-1);
  }
}

int main() {
  double n = updatedPI(3);
  cout << n << endl;
}
```

Comment: I don't think the answer is correct. There is no problem with sings. Only problem with OP's code is that `y` is wrong, since it is no equal to `2*n`.

Comment: @DanielLangr It seems you are saying the same thing I'm saying. The fact that there is a sign problem in his current code is because the relationship between his `y` and `n` is incorrect. I describe the actual computation to indicate that his incorrect relationship causes a sign problem. Or are you alluding to some other discrepancy?

Comment: You're right, sorry, I misinterpreted your answer, my bad. Unfortunately, I can't upvote it unless it is edited :(.

Comment: LaTeX doesn't work here, so you should probably just write in plain text as most people like me can't easily read LaTeX.

Answer (score 0):

The only problem with your code is that `y` is calculated incorrectly. It has to be equal to `2 * n`. Simply modifying your code that way gives correct results:

Live demo: https://wandbox.org/permlink/3pZNYZYbtHm7k1ND

That is, get rid of the `y` function parameter and set `int y = 2 * n;` in your function.